# Setting table name in a dynamically-defined class - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am working with a remote database (SQL Server 2008), and have a dynamic class definition, in which I am pointing to a specific table name like so:

```
  Object.const_set('Foo', Class.new(MyRemoteDB)) do
    self.table_name = ENV['TABLE_NAME']
    def self.go_wild
      ...
    end
  end
```

but when I try to access any methods defined in my dynamically-generated classes, Rails returns *Table doesn't exist*.

If I log the table name with `self.table_name`, I get the conventional plural version of the class name (e.g. `foos` for class name `Foo`, or `foo_bars` for `FooBar`) instead of the val I set with `self.table_name`.

Answer (score 2):

Turned out to be the way I am defining the dynamic class. Methods should be defined in a lambda, inside the `Object.const_set(...)` call:

```
Object.const_set('Foo', Class.new(MyRemoteDB){
  ...
  self.table_name = ENV['TABLE_NAME']
  ...
})
```